# Finding the sum of all columns in databricks error

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I'm new to Scala, and I basically want to perform a number of aggregations on a data set. Is it possible to group them all together or should I do each one separate (sum, min, max)?

This is what I've tried so far:

```
display(
  myDF
    .groupBy($"age","sex","cp","trestbps","chol")
    .sum()
)
```

And it's given me the following error message:

> error: overloaded method value groupBy with alternatives:
>
> (col1: String,cols:
>   String*)org.apache.spark.sql.RelationalGroupedDataset
>
> (cols:
>   org.apache.spark.sql.Column*)org.apache.spark.sql.RelationalGroupedDataset
>
> cannot be applied to (org.apache.spark.sql.ColumnName, String, String,
>   String, String)

Comment: try `groupBy($"age",$"sex",$"cp",$"trestbps",$"chol")`

Answer (score 0):

Do you want the sum of the whole column?
If so then

myDF.agg(sum("column name")).show()

your question is little unlcear. You can perform aggregations by using .agg(sum("column name"),max("column name"))